# jquery abstraction

Tags: jquery, abstraction, conflict

I've been prototyping a website using basic php skills and almost no js skills. I've been using various jquery and some prototype based modules (pop up forms, autocomplete etc) and probably got into conflicts. Someone suggested that I replace all the jquery references using "$(" with "jquery(", which has helped somewhat. I notice that I have syntax like "$." in a couple of places and wonder if that is a similar situation, but don't know what to replace it with. The obvious replacements (to me) didn't help, but there may be other unresolved issues, as well. Suggestions? I plan to standardize on jquery when I can spend more time to study options, but would like to patch the thing to run now.

Comment: When I first had this problem, I googled 'jQuery vs Prototype', read a bunch of opinions, and compared them with my own experience.  Now I only use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I've run into issues like this before, where multiple modules are using the $ shortcut syntax.  Look at all the javascript code you're including and try to track down the website(s) that supply them.  They should have an alternate syntax.

Likely culprits:

[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

[MooTools](http://mootools.net/)

[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)

I think I was playing around with [Tiki Wiki](http://info.tiki.org/) and had a conflict with that as well.

Comment: My question is: "I notice that I have syntax like "$." in a couple of places and wonder if that is a similar situation, but don't know what to replace it with."

Comment: Unless you post your code, we absolutely cannot know for sure.  I think my answer addresses the question the best I can with the amount of information you've offered.  If you look at the included javascript libraries, you'll probably find one that uses that shortcut syntax, and that'll be the culprit.  You need to figure that out, because the answer depends on what module is using it!

Comment: You may not be seeing the period in my text, it's hard to see in the font that displays in my browser.  Someone on another forum says that "jquery." should work to replace "$." This occurs in two different modules. One was an autocomplete that used "$.getJSON(acURL + part, function(json){...." and the other uses "$.ajax({  ...." in a popup form module. The latter module is working on most pages already, the autocomplete will probably be replaced with something that doesn't use JSON for the ajax.

Comment: `getJSON` and `ajax` are jquery functions.  I think everything's jquery that you're talking about.  You just need to replace all $ invocations with `jquery` ala `jquery.getJSON` and you should be fine.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/